# axios returns 404 for a post request with form data

Tags: node.js, express, axios, azure-active-directory, httprequest

I am trying to get a graph token from Azure AD with a post request having form data through Axios. The response throws an error **Request failed with status code 404**. The below is the code,

```
const axios = require('axios')
const FormData = require('form-data')
    
const bodyFormData = new FormData()
    
bodyFormData.append('client_id', <client id>)
bodyFormData.append('client_secret', <secret>)
bodyFormData.append('scope', <scope>)
bodyFormData.append('requested_token_use', <token use>)
bodyFormData.append('assertion', <token>)
    
axios
.post('https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantId>/oauth2/v2.0/token', bodyFormData, {
headers: bodyFormData.getHeaders(),
})
.then((response) => {
console.log('AXIOS RESPONSE ', response)
})
.catch((err) => {
console.log('AXIOS ERROR ', err)
})
```

The post request works fine in the postman. The response in Axios is also as expected if **bodyFormData** is removed from Axios request. When **bodyFormData** is added to the request I encounter an error.

**AXIOS ERROR  Error: Request failed with status code 404**

Comment: check `bodyFormData.getHeaders()`.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `form-data` use `querystring`

```js
const axios = require('axios')
const querystring = require('querystring');

const data = querystring.stringify({
    client_id: '<client id>',
    client_secret: '<secret>',
    scope: '<scope>',
    requested_token_use: '<token use>',
    assertion: '<token>'
});

axios.post('https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantId>/oauth2/v2.0/token', data)
    .then((response) => {
        console.log('AXIOS RESPONSE ', response)
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log('AXIOS ERROR ', err)
    });
```

Comment: Worked for me! Thanks a million

Comment: WHY does this fix it (because it did for us)?!

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the headers part, it should work.

There should not be any reason having to get the headers from the FormData object, as it’s an API and will use other forms of authentication and could mess up the call.

It’s not a data scraping call that might be blocked by some security measure.

Comment: please add some details. 
what are the reason that causes the problem and the logic behind your solution

Comment: I removed headers. Still, I am encountering the error. also, I have added cors in my node package. But still facing 404.

Comment: CORS should not be an issue as you are calling an external api.